# How can I plot data from an external JSON file to a chart.js graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to chart data from an external JSON file using chart.js. As an example, the json file [here](https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films) lists movies ("title") and ratings ("rt_score"). I'd like to be able to show each movie and its rating without including the static JSON in the .js file, but rather using the $.ajax call method to refer to the /films endpoint.

I'd like to have:

labels: labelsVariable
data: dataVariable

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsbin.com/tulasib/5/edit?html,js,output) with the setup so far with static data.

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
</body>
```

Here's the js that successfully generates a bar chart like I want, but with static data in "labels" and "data" instead of referencing the JSON file.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ['Castle in the Sky', 'Grave of the Fireflies'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'rating',
        data: [95, 97],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

Instead of using the static data and labels, how can I reference the external JSON file using the $.ajax call method?

Based on what I've read, I may have to use "map" to break down the objects into arrays that contain labels and data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's what worked. I had to use .map to set up the data properly inside variables and then use those variables as data and labels.

```
function renderChart(data, labels) {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'This week',
            data: data,
        }]
    },
});
}
function getChartData() {
$("#loadingMessage").html('<img src="./giphy.gif" alt="" srcset="">');
$.ajax({
    url: "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films",
    success: function (result) {
        var data = result.map(x=>x.rt_score);
        var labels = result.map(x=>x.title);
        renderChart(data, labels);
        console.log(data);
    },
});

$("#renderBtn").click(
function () {
    getChartData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the json chart data dynamically and set it when you are creating the graph. There are many ways you can load the chart json data. However, I believe the JQuery `getJSON` function is more relevant to you.

```
$.getJSON( "chartdata/test.json", function( data ) {


 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
 data: data,
 options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
  }
 });


}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do I get from the code you show above to being able to remove the string after "labels:" and after "data:"? I need to be able to place all of the movie titles into a variable and all of the rt_scores into a variable, right?

Comment: Please see the edited answer. The JSON you load dynamically should contain all what you had in the static version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Ajax request to fill your chart.

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var ctx_live = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor:'#00c0ef',
      label: 'liveCount',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js - Dynamically Update Chart Via Ajax Requests",
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
var postId = 1;
var getData = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + postId + '/comments',
    success: function(data) {
      myChart.data.labels.push("Post " + postId++);
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(getRandomIntInclusive(1, 25));

      // re-render the chart
      myChart.update();
    }
  });
};
setInterval(getData, 3000);
```

see live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/usjqfn0t/).